# UIPinchGesture ? why it show the scaled result only after I rotate the device

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview, gesture

I am try to use UIPinchGesture to scale a simple face that I draw by bezierPath, but when I use two finger to pinch the screen (either make it bigger or smaller), it does not show me result, only when I rotate the device, then the scaled face show up, really appreciate it for your suggestion about how to fix it:

below are my code that i use to implement the pinchGesture
in my faceView.swift:

```
func scale(gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer){
    if gesture.state == .Changed {
        scale *= gesture.scale
        gesture.scale = 1 
    }
}
```

in my ViewController.swift:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var faceView: FaceView! {
    didSet{
        faceView.dataSource = self
faceView.addGestureRecognizer(UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target:faceView,     
action:"scale:"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem shouldn't be in your code you pasted, because you know your scaling does work, it just doesn't draw it immediately. I believe you should declare FaceView's scale property with `{ didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }` to update the UI every time the scale gets changed.

At this moment, the UI gets updated only when you rotate your device.

Comment: Oh-That is it~!~!Thanks, I have set the first several vars with property observers , and just miss this one~~~:-)~~~Thanks very much!~!~!